# How to write formally about skipping one year of highschool on CV

Tags: cv

I’m writing a CV to apply to graduate schools right now. I’ve ran into problems translating some things in the CV.

How do I write the fact that I skipped one year of highschool formally? Should I just write -2016~2017: Highschool (skipped one year)? Or does this seem too informal?

Comment: What's the reason you need to mention high school?

Comment: Oh the school was a gifted highschool that is very competitive to get into. (Government funded Science Highschool in Korea) Therfore I just thought that it would work in favor of my application. However in retrsoepct, I’m pretty sure Americans wouldn’t know about that..

Comment: Is it weird to mention my highschool in the CV?

Comment: If your undergraduate performance doesn't match or exceed the prestige of attending that high school, then it will look as if you are not living up to your potential. If your undergraduate performance exceeds the prestige of attending that high school, then it doesn't matter -- and even then saying you attended could hurt, since even if you exceeded the prestige of attending that high school, some people might assume your attending that high school provided you with advantages not provided to others in the application pool, thereby possibly lowering their assessment of your aptitude.

Comment: Ahha thank you! I have been persuaded by your logic. I will remove them in the CV, thank you for the insight:)

Comment: That said, there can be times when it is appropriate to mention something from high school. For example, if someone received a bronze (or higher) medal in the [IMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mathematical_Olympiad), then it's almost certainly to that person's advantage to include this in an application to a graduate math program (indeed, I can't think of an exception), regardless of what that person accomplished as an undergraduate.

Comment: @DannyHan If you mention if in your CV, it might suggest that "skipping high school for a year" was one of your most important accomplishments so far. Is that what you want to tell the grad school?

Comment: Is skipping a year of school the same concept as skipping a day in school?

Comment: I assume the OP refers to skipping a grade, i.e. completing high school in a year less than normal.

Comment: Is this a US-type grade school application, i.e. you come from college, or have you done a full 8-10 semester university education?

Comment: @Karl It is a US grad school application (i.e. I come from a 8 semester university education)

Comment: @alephzero: I'd be surprised if the majority of phd appliciants had skipped a year in school or had one bigger acomplishment. I, for one, had neither.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

High school attendance is not mentioned on an academic CV.

Comment: Well, the first time I was asked for a CV, I was *in* high school, so there are exceptions ...

Comment: I would say that it depends on the country. Mentioning Louis Le Grand, Henri IV or Hoche  as your high school in France would not be surprising. Unusual yes, but not surprising (these are elite high schools, with Hoche being obviously, of course and by far the best one (I therefore announce the war open /s))

Comment: *quietly deleting high school from my CV*

Comment: I don't really know about the American system, but I think it depends. For example if your only academic achievements so far are, say, a BSc and a MSc and you have no work experience, and you also got a German Abitur with average grade 1,0, then I would definitely include a line like "2011, Abitur mit Schnitt 1,0". It still wouldn't matter if a grade was skipped because you would just use the year of the diploma.

Comment: Fun fact I agree, but then again a company asked me for my highschool grades, after having a bachelor. I politely declined to proceed.

Comment: I disagree. I have it on my CV, briefly. As in "1888–1900: Went to school X, passed final exam Y". At least on my German academic CV, in the full version – that thing listing all your papers, all your lectures, and spanning pages and pages on. Admittedly, it got carried over from my student times, but no one ever told me it's that irrelevant. This might be a US thing, thus, EU perception might be different.

Comment: Oh, and as a matter of fact, commercial companies were asking _funny_ things. Interim school grades. Interim uni grades. High school diploma when already showing MSc diploma and PhD diploma. *sighs* Fun!

Answer (score 8):

It also depends on the school system and on what „high school“ means in that context. The same term means different things in the UK and the USA, for example, and it is often used when translating from German school system even though it does not exactly match the system there.

Comment: What's the difference between the UK and the US?

Comment: I recommend this link to get some idea of the differences: https://www.buzzfeed.com/jameskicksa/i-have-broken-down-the-differences-between-us-and-uk-school

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely want to mention your high school with a skipped year, maybe because your CV would otherwise be a bit meager or because you went to a very prestigious high school, I would reference it as "accelerated". [Academic Acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_acceleration) is a formal enough term for a CV, and most academics would probably be aware of the concept and can probably read enough into the term to understand you reference grade skipping.

Comment: And you don't have to mention the skipped year. You actually wouldn't even mention the start year! Nobody is interested in it. Simply stating the *graduation* year is totally sufficient. It's basically the starting point of your academic career.

Answer (score 0):

No one cares about high school once you have your college degree, either in grad school applications or in professions - it's simply not relevant. I'm currently working on my second master's degree and have been working in industry for many years, and I only recall one employer that asked about high school.

Comment: Can you mention the countries your experience is about? I had different experience..